# Eloquent Model Relationship Multiple Key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Take this example:

> ModelA - Connects to Cloud Database
>
> ModelB - Connects to Local Database

I want to create a one to one relationship between these models with multiple key conditions.

Something Like this...

```
$owner->hasOne(
'App\Http\Models\VMS\CashierCollectionModel'
, 'ModelA_PKey_Foo', 'ModelB_FKey_Foo'
, 'ModelA_PKey_Bar', 'ModelB_FKey_Bar');
```

is there anyway I can do these using Eloquent?

Edit :

I dont have any problem connecting my models to databases. My problem is setting the relationship between my two models.

Comment: you can use two different connections for two database one for cloud and one for local, i will send you code for that

Comment: What are `Owner` and `CashierCollectionModel`?